# Spotbugs exclude filter in gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, findbugs, spotbugs

I am new to gradle and am trying to configure Spotbugs.
I've added the plugin to the build.gradle and the spotbugs issues showed up.
However I want to exclude the Findbugs EI_EXPOSE_REP and EI_EXPOSE_REP2 rules, because they show up for all my getter and setters.
I have the following snippet in build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.github.spotbugs'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'

spotbugs {
    toolVersion = '5.0.0'
}

tasks.withType(SpotBugsTask) {
    reports {
        xml.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
    }
}

findbugs {
    excludeFilter = file("$rootProject.projectDir/config/findbugs/excludeFilter.xml")
    toolVersion = "3.0.1"
    effort = "max"
}
```

The excludeFilter.xml contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FindBugsFilter>
    <Match>
        <Bug pattern="EI_EXPOSE_REP"/>
    </Match>
    <Match>
        <Bug pattern="EI_EXPOSE_REP2"/>
    </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

I also tried adding the exclude like this:

```
tasks.withType(FindBugs) {
    excludeFilter = file("$rootProject.projectDir/config/findbugs/excludeFilter.xml")
}
```

But it didn't work out, so probably I am missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the exclude filter to the spotbugs configuration instead of findbugs:
so you should probably try:

```
spotbugs {
    toolVersion = '5.0.0'
    excludeFilter.set(file("${spotbugsConfigDir}/excludeFilter.xml"))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following lines add the SpotBugs 5.0.14 plugin to a Gradle project:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath "com.github.spotbugs.snom:spotbugs-gradle-plugin:5.0.14"
  }
}

plugins {
  id 'application'
  id "com.github.spotbugs" version "5.0.14"
}

spotbugs {
  excludeFilter.set(
      file("${projectDir}/bug-filter.xml")
  )
}
```

Create the file `bug-filter.xml` in the project's root directory. See the [Filter file documentation](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filter.html) (or [PDF version](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/spotbugs/latest/spotbugs.pdf)) for details on the available options. Insert the following short snippet into the file to ignore EI and EI2 errors across all classes:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FindBugsFilter>
  <Match>
    <Or>
      <Bug code="EI, EI2" />
    </Or>
  </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

The [Bug descriptions](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/bugDescriptions.html) page lists bug codes and patterns.

The `FindBugsFilter` root-level element name is a holdover.

---

As a side-note, too many accessors tend to indicate code isn't reaping the benefits of [object-oriented programming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YyIQKBzIuBY&t=1152s).

Answer (score 0):

*Extension to [@Dave Jarvis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76196034/3679900) above*

---

Specifying following in `build.gradle` worked for me

```
spotbugs {
  ignoreFailures.set(false)
  excludeFilter = file('spotbugs-exclude.xml')
}
```

Other variations that I've seen are

- `excludeFilter = project.file('spotbugs-exclude.xml')`
- `excludeFilter.set(file('spotbugs-exclude.xml'))`

*I had put the file in root-level of my project so I specified just the name of file; otherwise we can put something like `file('${project.projectDir}/configuration/spotBugs/excludeFilter.xml')` for specifying complete filepath*

---

Do note that exclusion for unit-tests might possibly have to be configured separately in a `spotbugsTest { .. }` block of it's own (although we can still specify the same XML file)

```
spotbugs {
  ignoreFailures.set(true)
  excludeFilter = file('spotbugs-exclude-src.xml')
}

spotbugsTest {
  ignoreFailures.set(false)
  excludeFilter = file('spotbugs-exclude-tst.xml')
}
```

For format of `spotbugs-exclude.xml` file see [FindBugs/FilterFiles](https://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html)

Comment: For format of `spotbugs-exclude.xml` file, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77018958/3679900) or [this](https://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html)